# How to set current time to future time by using Cypress?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor, cypress-component-test-runner

I am using cypress to automate countdown content block, I need to test recurrence scenarios by using Cypress. In Example,

At the Start - Days - 00 | Hrs - 00 | Mins - 00

I need to validate, after one hour, count down will be started (Days - 23 | Hrs - 59 | Mins - 59)

I cannot use hard-coded wait times, so I try the following cypress script but It won't work.

```
const now = new Date().getTime()
cy.clock(now)
cy.tick(3600000)
```

Anything worng in this? Or help me to find a good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create the currentNow you want and then set it

```
    const now = new Date(2011, 0, 11) // month is 0-indexed
    cy.clock(now)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use [`moment`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) library, so it will take current time + one hour, and so on

```
const afterOneHour = moment().add(+1, 'h').format('HH:mm');
```

like on example [here](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/03-manipulating/01-add/)

Comment: I had read Cypress had Moment as a integrated dependency in the past. What happened there?